# EmberJS expose env variable as route

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I would like to configure a URL differently in my ember app depending if the app is running in production or development mode. Is this possible to do by loading the endpoints into `config/environment.js` and accessing the value of the ENV object in a handlebars template? Maybe I have to expose the ENV value in a controller? Or is there some other mechanism for doing this?

Something like this:

```
// config/environment.js

if (environment === 'development') {
  ENV.zzz.url = "http://www.reddit.com";
}

if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV.zzz.url = "http://www.google.com";
}

// app/controllers/application.js

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  siteUrl: ENV.zzz.url
  ...

// somefile.hbs

<a href="{{siteUrl}}">Funspot</a>
```

Comment: Happened to dig up this after the fact, which essentially is a more detailed version of below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323852/correct-way-to-access-current-application-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. you can do `import config from 'app-name/config/environment';`
and access it like `config.zzz.url`